# iOS: image drawing performance

Tags: ios, performance, drawing

I have several fundamental questions to clearify to myself, hope you'll help...

I'm developing a game application. It has game loop and on each iteration i draw about 200 sprites. What is the fastest way of drawing bitmap? Currently I use `[UIImage drawAtPoint]` method to draw a sprite (sprite sizes can be 16x16 ... 64x64), but something tells me, this is not the best approach. As I understand, UIImage is based on Quartz technology? Can cocos2d provide the better performance?
I also thought about using OpenGL ES to reproduce drawing mechanism via textured objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're making a game you'll probably want to avoid Quartz/UIKit/CoreAnimation.  They're designed to be simple and easy to use, at the cost of performance.

Opengl is the fastest way to draw sprites to the screen on the iPhone.  There are two versions of Opengl in iOS: OpenglES 1.1 and OpenglES 2.0.  If you're looking to support the iphone 3G and earlier, you'll need to either use 1.1 exclusively, or be able to determine the device you're running on and switch versions on the fly.  Opengl is very fast but at the cost of a fairly steep learning curve and a lot of what you'd see as boilerplate code.

Cocos2d is an iOS game engine built on top of Opengl.  It's designed to make using opengl easier (among many other things).  If you're making a game, I'd suggest you use cocos2d as they've done a lot of the hard work already.  If you don't you'll be spending 99% of your time getting opengl to work, rather than focusing on the game.

Good luck! :)

Comment: thank you for good answer, if there is no opinion anymore, i'll accept your one. i'll try cocos2d although I have sucessful experience with OpenGL ES)). One thing that is not clear to me yet is how to deal with coordinate system in my task context. when i invoke [UIImage drawAtPoint:(CGRect) target] i'm sure, it will be drawn right in the target.frame.origin coordinates. But if i initialize verticies coordinates array for OpenGL primitive with the same target.frame.origin values it won't be drawn at the place i expect...

Comment: That's because UIKit is drawing directly to the screen coordinate frame.  In other words all the coordinates of images drawn with UIKit are relative to the bounds of the screen.  OpenglES specifies things in world space coordinates and then converts the world space coordinates to screen space coordinates when rendering.  Basically it takes the vertices of objects you create and multiplies them by a matrix that describes how to convert from world to screenspace... Like I said before, this gives you a lot more flexibility and power, however it can get a little tricky.

Comment: one more question. while experimenting with cocos2d i've created a simple project with couple of sprites that do some animation and run it under Allocations Instrument. It has encountered about 5Mb of allocations. Is it normal for cocos2d?

Comment: Sounds reasonable.  Cocoas2d has some memory overhead to get the system working in addition to the memory the textures for the sprites take up.  If you're running on an iPhone 3GS or later, the graphics and system memory are shared, so this could also be counting texture memory.